# How do I close all buffers that aren't shown in a window in vim?

Tags: vim

I have a horde of buffers open in vim, with only a few of them open in split windows or on other tabs.  Is there a way to close all but the ones that are currently visible in one of those splits or tabs?

Comment: For reference, I found this [Yahoo Vim Group thread](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/56425) before I came across this SO Q&A. The answers here are better since they deal with tab pages.

Comment: Artem Nezvigin has adapted the myriad solutions below into a plugin, [wipeout.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4882)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution you can drop in your `.vimrc`:

```
function! Wipeout()
  " list of *all* buffer numbers
  let l:buffers = range(1, bufnr('$'))

  " what tab page are we in?
  let l:currentTab = tabpagenr()
  try
    " go through all tab pages
    let l:tab = 0
    while l:tab < tabpagenr('$')
      let l:tab += 1

      " go through all windows
      let l:win = 0
      while l:win < winnr('$')
        let l:win += 1
        " whatever buffer is in this window in this tab, remove it from
        " l:buffers list
        let l:thisbuf = winbufnr(l:win)
        call remove(l:buffers, index(l:buffers, l:thisbuf))
      endwhile
    endwhile

    " if there are any buffers left, delete them
    if len(l:buffers)
      execute 'bwipeout' join(l:buffers)
    endif
  finally
    " go back to our original tab page
    execute 'tabnext' l:currentTab
  endtry
endfunction
```

Use `:call Wipeout()`.

Comment: Does this delete modified buffers?

Comment: the answer by atomicules works, this one deletes buffers in tabs and seems to have odd behavior.

Comment: Careful - `Wipeout()` considers windows in other tabs (tabs that are not the currently visible tab) to be invisible.

Answer (score 29):

Yet another take on this. Using the example given in the Vim help for `tabpagebuflist()` to get a list of the buffers that appear in a tab or window. I have the below in my `.vimrc`

```
function! DeleteInactiveBufs()
    "From tabpagebuflist() help, get a list of all buffers in all tabs
    let tablist = []
    for i in range(tabpagenr('$'))
        call extend(tablist, tabpagebuflist(i + 1))
    endfor

    "Below originally inspired by Hara Krishna Dara and Keith Roberts
    "http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/56425
    let nWipeouts = 0
    for i in range(1, bufnr('$'))
        if bufexists(i) && !getbufvar(i,"&mod") && index(tablist, i) == -1
        "bufno exists AND isn't modified AND isn't in the list of buffers open in windows and tabs
            silent exec 'bwipeout' i
            let nWipeouts = nWipeouts + 1
        endif
    endfor
    echomsg nWipeouts . ' buffer(s) wiped out'
endfunction
command! Bdi :call DeleteInactiveBufs()
```

Comment: This breaks CommandT. I get "Vim::DeletedBufferError: attempt to refer to deleted buffer" the first time I activate CommandT after running Bdi. The next time I try CommandTs keybinding, nothing happens at all and several of my other keybindings also stop working.

Comment: @bobpaul I don't use CommandT, but you could try using `bdelete` instead of `bwipeout` in the function. That might upset CommandT less.

Comment: Hi atomicules, I'm trying your function, and I get a bunch of errors like this: http://trusktr.io:7777/isowiyirid.rb . Any ideas?

Comment: @trusktr Sorry, only just seen your comment. The page you've linked to is now blank. From the .rb extension I'm guessing this was another CommandT conflict? If so, really can't help as I don't use it.

Comment: @atomicules Oops, I guess my server deletes pastes after a certain (not a bad idea, maybe I can add an option to lock it). I was trying your function and getting errors. Oh well, no time for it right now.

Comment: @bobpaul You can always user https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim instead of CommandT. Its better maintained and quite a bit more versatile anyway.

Answer (score 11):

Add this to your .vimrc:

```
function! CloseHiddenBuffers()
  let i = 0
  let n = bufnr('$')
  while i < n
    let i = i + 1
    if bufloaded(i) && bufwinnr(i) < 0
      exe 'bd ' . i
    endif
  endwhile
endfun
```

Then you can do this to close hidden buffers:

```
:call CloseHiddenBuffers()
```

(You'll probably want to bind a key or a command to it.)

**Update:**

Here's a version updated to support tab pages. (I don't use tab pages myself, so I hadn't realized that bufwinnr only works for windows on the current page).

```
function! CloseHiddenBuffers()
  " figure out which buffers are visible in any tab
  let visible = {}
  for t in range(1, tabpagenr('$'))
    for b in tabpagebuflist(t)
      let visible[b] = 1
    endfor
  endfor
  " close any buffer that's loaded and not visible
  for b in range(1, bufnr('$'))
    if bufloaded(b) && !has_key(visible, b)
      exe 'bd ' . b
    endif
  endfor
endfun
```

Comment: I may have phrased my question incorrectly—I'm trying to clean up the output of `:ls` and this function doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Was it the lack of tab-page support, or something else? I've added a version that supports tab-pages, above.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? (Also, what version of vim are you using?)

Comment: /me pretends a 1.5 years hasn't passed...

I'm running vim 7.3.  I don't see any of the background buffers go away with your function—running
`:ls`
`:call CloseHiddenBuffers`
`:ls`
results in no change in the ls output.

Answer (score 6):

There's a **plugin** that does exactly this and a bit more!

Check out **[close-buffers.vim](https://github.com/Asheq/close-buffers.vim)**

Comment: Awesome. `:CloseHiddenBuffers`

Comment: @cdosborn maybe the syntax has changed, I believe now it would translate to `:Bdelete hidden` for which I use this mapping: `map <leader>bh :Bdelete hidden<cr>`

Answer (score 4):

I know why the second script doesn't work properly.

This is due to the bufloaded() function which must be bufexits() !

Indeed, a buffer to delete is not loaded ! Just remove this condition is okay but it is doing some warning when we are trying to wipe out a buffer not used so we have to use bufexists(b).

The final solution is the following:

```
function! CloseHiddenBuffers()
    " Tableau pour memoriser la visibilite des buffers                                                                                      
    let visible = {}
    " Pour chaque onglet...
    for t in range(1, tabpagenr('$'))
        " Et pour chacune de ses fenetres...
        for b in tabpagebuflist(t)
            " On indique que le buffer est visible.
            let visible[b] = 1
        endfor
    endfor
    " Pour chaque numero de buffer possible...
    for b in range(1, bufnr('$'))
        " Si b est un numero de buffer valide et qu'il n'est pas visible, on le
        " supprime.
        if bufexists(b) && !has_key(visible, b)
            " On ferme donc tous les buffers qui ne valent pas 1 dans le tableau et qui
            " sont pourtant charges en memoire.
            execute 'bwipeout' b
        endif
    endfor
endfun
```

Thanks to you.

Comment: If "bufloaded(b)" is false for exactly the buffers we want to close, why not just "if !bufloaded(b)"?

Comment: This did the trick, and but I quite like :Wipeout very catchy `command! -nargs=? Wipeout call CloseHiddenBuffers()`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using fzf, here's a way to select buffers to delete:

```
" fzf delete buffers
function! s:list_buffers()
  redir => list
  silent ls
  redir END
  return split(list, "\n")
endfunction
function! s:delete_buffers(lines)
  execute 'bwipeout' join(map(a:lines, {_, line -> split(line)[0]}))
endfunction
command! BD call fzf#run(fzf#wrap({
  \ 'source': s:list_buffers(),
  \ 'sink*': { lines -> s:delete_buffers(lines) },
  \ 'options': '--multi --reverse --bind ctrl-a:select-all+accept'
  \ }))
```