# How can I pare down Vim's buffer list to only include active buffers

Tags: vim

How can I pare down my buffer list to only include buffers that are currently open in a window/tab?

When I've been running Vim for a long time, the list of buffers revealed by the `:ls` command is too large to work with. Ideally, I would like to delete all of the buffers which are not currently visible in a tab or window by running a custom command such as `:Only`. Can anybody suggest how to achieve this?

It looks like the [`:bdelete`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:bdelete) command can accept a list of buffer numbers, but I'm not sure how to translate the output from `:ls` to a format that can be consumed by the `:bdelete` command. Any help would be appreciated.

### Clarification

Lets say that in my Vim session I have opened 4 files. The `:ls` command outputs:

```
:ls
1  a   "abc.c"
2  h   "123.c"
3  h   "xyz.c"
4  a   "abc.h"
```

Buffer 1 is in the current tab, and and buffer 4 is in a separate tab, but
buffers 2 and 3 are both hidden. I would like to run the command `:Only`, and
it would wipe buffers 2 and 3, so the `:ls` command would output:

```
:ls
1  a   "abc.c"
4  a   "abc.h"
```

This example doesn't make the proposed `:Only` command look very useful, but
if you have a list of 40 buffers it would be very welcome.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534835/how-do-i-close-all-buffers-that-arent-shown-in-a-window-in-vim

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've adapted [Laurence Gonslaves solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534835/how-do-i-close-all-buffers-that-arent-shown-in-a-window-in-vim/1534979#1534979).

```
command! -nargs=* Only call CloseHiddenBuffers()
function! CloseHiddenBuffers()
  " figure out which buffers are visible in any tab
  let visible = {}
  for t in range(1, tabpagenr('$'))
    for b in tabpagebuflist(t)
      let visible[b] = 1
    endfor
  endfor
  " close any buffer that are loaded and not visible
  let l:tally = 0
  for b in range(1, bufnr('$'))
    if bufloaded(b) && !has_key(visible, b)
      let l:tally += 1
      exe 'bw ' . b
    endif
  endfor
  echon "Deleted " . l:tally . " buffers"
endfun
```

I changed it to use `bwipeout` instead of `bdelete`, and added the message to show how many buffers have been removed.

Comment: Also, using buflisted(b) instead of bufloaded(b) will clean up the :ls list, especially after switching between sessions, which is what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for:

```
:echo map(filter(range(0, bufnr('$')), 'bufwinnr(v:val)>=0'), 'bufname(v:val)')
```

or more precisely:

```
exe 'bw '.join(filter(range(0, bufnr('$')), 'bufwinnr(v:val)<0'), ' ')
```

?

---

EDIT: The previous answer did not take multiple tabs into account.

It seems I used a complex approach. The list of opened, and displayed, buffers can be obtained thanks to `tabpagebuflist()` with:

```
let tabs = range(1, tabpagenr())
echo lh#list#unique_sort(eval(join(map(tabs, 'tabpagebuflist(v:val)'), '+')))
```

(`lh#list#unique_sort()` comes from [lh-vim-lib](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhVimLib), it defines the sort+unique function that vim does not provide)

In order to have the non opened buffers, it becomes a little bit more tricky. Either we use a loop of each tab to obtain the buffers non displayed, or we make a diff between the previous result and the bufexisting buffers:

```
let tabs = range(1, tabpagenr())
let windowed = lh#list#unique_sort(eval(join(map(tabs, 'tabpagebuflist(v:val)'), '+')))
let existing = filter(range(0,bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(v:val)')
let non_windowed = filter(copy(existing), 'match(windowed, "^".v:val."$")<0')  
echo non_windowed
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great start, but it has a fatal flaw: [bufwinnr only deals with the current tab page](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#bufwinnr\(\)). If I have more than 1 tab open, the window(s) in the active tab will be preserved, but the buffers in the other tabs will be nuked.

Answer (score 1):

```
" Active Buffers
function ListActive()
    let result = ""
    silent! redir => result
    silent! exe "ls"
    redir END
    let active = ""
    for i in split(result, "\n")
      if matchstr(i, '\m[0-9][0-9]* .a.. ') != ""
        let active .= "\n".i
      endif
    endfor
    echo active
endfunction
```

E.g.

From shell:

```
$ vim -p foo bar baz
```

Inside vim:

```
:call ListActive()
```

Output:

```
1 %a   "foo"                          line 1
2  a   "bar"                          line 0
3  a   "baz"                          line 0
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Close one file:

```
:q

:call ListActive()
```

Output:

```
2 %a   "bar"                          line 1
3  a   "baz"                          line 0
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Open another file:

```
:split ~/.vimrc

:call ListActive()
```

Output:

```
2 #a   "bar"                          line 1
3  a   "baz"                          line 0
4 %a   "~/.vimrc"                     line 244
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have say 4 buffers open:

```
:ls
1    abc.c
2    123.c
3    xyz.c
4    abc.h
```

and you want to "close" buffer 3 "xyz.c":

```
:bd3
```

results after deleting buffer 3:

```
:ls
1    abc.c
2    123.c
4    abc.h
```

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for, but thanks for taking the time to answer. I've posted a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `set hidden`, so my desire to close buffers that aren't shown in any window is simply to clear up the output of `:ls`.  This function does just that:

```
function! CloseUnloadedBuffers()
    let lastBuffer = bufnr('$')

    let currentBuffer = 1
    while currentBuffer <= lastBuffer
        " If buffer exists, is shown in :ls output, and isn't loaded
        if bufexists(currentBuffer) && buflisted(currentBuffer) && bufloaded(currentBuffer) == 0
            execute 'bdelete' currentBuffer
        endif

        let currentBuffer = currentBuffer + 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

[From this Nabble thread](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/close-all-unvisible-buffers-td4262697.html)