# Close all the tabs except the active one?

Tags: vim

Is there any way to close all the tabs except the active one?

tags: current

Answer (score 107):

```
:tabo[nly]
```

You might want to read

```
:help tab
```

Comment: This doesn't close the buffers for the other tabs though. any idea how to do that?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534835/how-do-i-close-all-buffers-that-arent-shown-in-a-window-in-vim/1534979#1534979) to close hidden buffers.

Answer (score 43):

Why not

```
:tabonly     - close all other tabs (show only the current tab)
```

? See [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages) for more info